# Extending filetype functionality?

Tags: filetype

I'm trying to add some functionality by adding `ftplugin` files.

For instance I want to add `nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :source %<CR>` to `ftplugin/vim.vim`, but when I try it, it looks like vim it's only sourcing the plugin for the first instance of a `vim` filetype.
eg.
Opening `init.vim` works perfectly but then I open (in the same instance of `nvim`), `ftplugin/python.vim` and this file shows with no filetype no syntax highlighting, and no mappings.

What could be going on in this case?

Comment: This is supposed to work. But it's hard to tell why it isn't in your case. What is the full path to the extension `vim.vim` you're writing? What are the full contents of that file? If you have a single line there, does it work or not work? Make sure you check `:messages` to see if there's any errors there. See also `:scriptnames`, it will list the paths of all scripts that were sourced, in order. Ah, one more thing, check that `:set ft?` for the second file actually reports `filetype=vim`.

Comment: (Aside) The mapping should be buffer-local

Comment: It's on `!~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/vim.vim`, yes the `ft` is setting correctly, but still doesn't load any syntax highlighting nor local mappings.